# python normalizing large numbers

Tags: python, machine-learning, normalization

I'm working on a chatbot programme to practice python in general and a bit of sklearn machine learning algorithmic.

For now I'm just giving the chatbot random sentences and telling it if the sentences are correct or not. Each word is assigned key for itself, its type (grammar) and mood (positive, negative, neutral, vulgar, etc...).

After each input given the sentence is saved to a csv file.
Each sentence has three features : key, key_type, key_mood and one label :0 (incorrect) and 1(correct).

At first, for each key, I had a list of the corresponding key for each word. I thought it was a good idea as it would keep track of the order in which the words were inserted.

Unfortunately when saved to csv the lists are transformed into strings containing the lists and I don't know how to extract the lists from the string (and even if I knew how to, I don't know if you can feed an array of lists to a model, my guess is probably not).

So I came up with this : instead of having a list of feature I can have a number that represents this list of numbers:

```
for word in self.words:
    for key in word.word_dict():
        sentence_dict[key] += int(float(word.word_dict()[key]))* 10 **(3*n)
    n+=1
```

So for example the "key" key for "How are you" would be 8007006, 8 being "How"'s word key, 7 "are"'s and 6 "you"'s.
Similarly, the "key_type" for this sentence is 12002001, 12 for "question word", 2 for "verb" and 1 for "pronoun"

This works fine and the model can actually read the features and cross_validate.
Unfortunately because of the way these keys are made I end up with huge numbers and rather small numbers in the same dataset and I think it throws the models off.

I tried normalizing using np.sigmoid but this just outputs 1 for most of my keys(they're just too large).

So my question is : is there a way to normalize these keys in a way to not defeat their purpose? If not do you have a better idea as to how to feed these keys to the model without losing the order in which the individual word keys were added?

Or is it one or those cases where neural networks are necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using CSV files to store the data, how about using [JSON](http://json.org/) instead?

JSON is available in the Python standard library (see [JSON](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)).  Storing the data as JSON would preserve the dict and list structures and is really easy to work with.  For example:

```
import json
original_sentence = {
    'key': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
}
result = json.dumps(original_sentence)  # '{"key": ["a", "b", "c"]}'
```

Then when you need to use the data:

```
loaded_sentence = json.loads(result)
```

To show that you get the same data back:

```
print(original_sentence == loaded_sentence)
```

You can write the JSON one line at a time into your output file, or you can make the results a list and dump the entire list of results to a single JSON file.

```
results = [sentence for sentence in sentences]
with open('output.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(results, fp)  # notice .dump not .dumps

with open('output.json') as fp:
    results = json.load(fp)  # notice .load not .loads
```

**Note:** if you have more complex objects then you might need to make the objects serializable, but if you're storing them in CSV that's highly unlikely.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that. The object that I transform to CSV is  a PD dataframe. Would that work?

Comment: If im not mistaken, PD dataframes already have `.to_json` and `.read_json` methods so you can use those directly.

Comment: I just confirmed, pandas dataframes do have a `.to_json` method, but the `read_json` is part of pandas, not the dataframe specifically.  So to create the json `data = df.to_json()` and to restore it `pd.read_json(data)`